# Mysql - Select difference of the average of same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm trying to find the difference between the average of multiple values from same column.

Here is the schema.

```
CREATE TABLE `product_priceDiff` (
  `mark` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `markId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `found_date` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `found_price` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_date` date DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `confirmed_price` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_difference` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mark`,`markId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

And here are some sample values

```
+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
| mark             | markId   | found_date | found_price | confirmation_date | confirmed_price | price_difference | action |
+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
| soap             |        6 | 2014-01-13 |       0.410 | 2014-01-15        |           0.420 |            2.439 | BUY    |
| lotion           |        7 | 2013-09-13 |       0.000 | 2013-09-13        |           0.170 |            0.000 | BUY    |
| shaving_cream    |        8 | 2014-01-09 |      41.500 | 2014-01-10        |          42.000 |            1.205 | BUY    |    | 
| hairgel          |       19 | 2014-01-13 |       8.220 | 2014-01-16        |           8.190 |           -0.365 | SELL   |
| aftershaves      |       20 | 2011-07-12 |       0.000 | 2011-07-12        |           7.500 |            0.000 | SELL   |
| shampoo          |       21 | 2014-01-14 |      46.870 | 2014-01-17        |          46.480 |           -0.832 | SELL   |
+------------------+----------+------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
```

What i want to find is the average price difference. The formula is

```
Average(price_difference) @ BUY - Average(price_difference) @ SELL
```

i tried doing it using this query but it doesn't work at all

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN `action` = "BUY" THEN `price_difference`) 
    - AVG(CASE WHEN `action` = "SELL" THEN `price_difference`) 
    FROM `product_priceDiff`;
```

This gives me an error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'action = "BUY" then price_difference) - avg(case
>   when action= "SELL" then  price' at line 1

Please provide any advice on what should i do to get the required values. Thanks, in advance

Maxx

Comment: you youst miss`END`statement on the case:`CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <action> END`

Comment: Yes that worked the error is gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to record:

The problem is "syntax" of [CASE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).

```
CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <action> END
```

You miss the `END`

Comment: Yes it works now. I wasn't fully aware of the proper syntax of SELECT CASES before. Thanks for the answer.